# How to delete row in same tabke after row insert using trigger with X minutes in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to delete row after 5 minutes from same table after insert new row using trigger in phpmyadmin.

Comment: You cannot action a table in a trigger which was fired by that table.

Comment: any option to use same logic using event ?

Comment: The only option you have to schedule a task in MYSQL is an event(s). Fairly straightforward if you timestamp on insert but it sounds like you are just purging the table completely so why not run a truncate at end of day?

Comment: I need to delete the inserted row after some minutes .  is there any option ?

Comment: Why would you think an event to delete would not work for you?

Comment: Then  how can i delete that particular row after 5 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188865/discussion-between-abdul-kadhar-and-p-salmon).

Comment: Let's not. It would we good if you shared your table definition, and the delete statement you would use and the event code you may have written.